# Can I omit the Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the response headers when responding “204 no content ” to a simple request?

Tags: cors

I'm maintaining both client and server sides of the application and I’m trying to minimize my response size. 
The client run in different domain from the server but all the requests count as “simple requests”
As for now, I’m following the cors rules and adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to all of my responses. 
Is it possible to omit it?
As far as I understand, if the request is “simple”, no preflight request will be triggered and if the response body is empty (204) there is no further processing on the response. 
Am I right?

Comment: You're right, the browser will do no further processing of the 204 response. So it's not strictly necessary for the 204 response to have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. If the 204 response lacks that header, the only consequence will be that the browser logs a CORS error message in the devtools console.

Answer (score -1):

Sort of - it's only necessary on the response to the pre-flight OPTIONS request.

There's not really a concept of a "simple" request, there is just the pre-flight request, then the real request. The pre-flight is the browser asking the server if it's ok to make the subsequent "real" request and any rules about what can be sent on that request (credentials, cookies, specific headers and so on)

If you are not doing cross origin requests from javascript (eg making requests to a different host that the one that served the page) then the browser wont make a pre-flight request.

Other ways to minimise over the wire payloads are:

- request and response compression
- use HTTP2

Comment: Not all requests executed from different domain requires preflight request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). My requests are POST with content type plain/text and no other headers, so no preflight is needed. Yet, most of the resources I found, mention that you need to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to all responses.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer. However you only need the Access-Control headers on the pre-flight request / response. The real request, in this case the POST, does not care about the Access control headers as CORS is simply a mechanism to tell the browser if it is allowed to make a request or not.